# WebRTC no video after second call

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webrtc

I try to integrate in my project WebRTC [from here](https://github.com/stasel/WebRTC-iOS)

In first call all are fine and I have video, but in second and other calls no. I tried

-socket.disconnect();

- in VideoViewController

  ```
      deinit{
      self.localVideoView = nil
       self.webRTCClient.delegate = nil
       }
  ```

  - make disconnect in ViewController add new Button for connect and other for disconnect:

    ```
    @IBAction func connectBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.webRTCClient.delegate = self
    self.signalClient.delegate = self
    self.hasLocalSdp = true
    self.hasRemoteSdp = true
    self.signalClient.connect()
    }


    @IBAction func disconnectBtn(_ sender: UIButton) {
    self.webRTCClient.peerConnection.close()
    self.signalingConnected = false
    signalClient.socket.disconnect()
    self.localCandidateCount = 0
    self.remoteCandidateCount = 0
    self.hasLocalSdp = false
    self.hasRemoteSdp = false
    }
    ```
  - adding delegates in ViewWillAppear(when close VideoViewController they must create new delegates):

    ```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    self.webRTCClient.remoteStream = nil
    self.signalingConnected = false
    self.hasLocalSdp = false
    self.hasRemoteSdp = false
    self.localCandidateCount = 0
    self.remoteCandidateCount = 0
    self.speakerOn = false
    self.signalClient.connect()
    self.webRTCClient.delegate = self
    self.signalClient.delegate = self
      }
    ```

Nothing help for me

Links from Debug area
 on first call https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SpOm-udTvWYxVSVTBA4j4OKsIcNC9XiS1WmtnkIEhLo/edit?usp=sharing

on second https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TROAkqqOxVl9oTvsiD2WMzQccGBf2jtd6O3KVBCNdMc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you please share second call with us?

Comment: link doesn`t work?